# ComboBoxes sharing Observable Collection keeps breaking

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have four comboboxes that are experiencing a weird quirk. Its hard for me to explain exactly whats going on... so I put it in a video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OuB-kSGMMSo

```
<ComboBox x:Name="images1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="3"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="images2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="images3" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Margin="3"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="images4" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Margin="3"/>
```

Code behind

```
public ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem> images =
    new ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem>();

public ImageSelect(MainWindow mainWindow, string tab_name)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Generic.ImportImages(tab_name, images1, images);

    images2.ItemsSource = images;
    images3.ItemsSource = images;
    images4.ItemsSource = images;
}
```

My class

```
public static void ImportImages(string tabID, ComboBox combo, ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem> list)
{
    try
    {
        string root = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(root, "input\\" + tabID), "*.png");

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            string[] paths = file.Split('\\');
            ComboBoxItem item = new ComboBoxItem();
            item.Tag = paths.Last();

            var stack = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };
            stack.Children.Add(new Image() { Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(file, UriKind.Absolute)), Height = 44 });
            stack.Children.Add(new Label() { Content = paths.Last(), VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center });
            item.Content = stack;

            list.Add(item);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception) { }

    combo.ItemsSource = list;
}
```

Comment: A UI element cannot exist in more than one place in the visual tree (or more than one visual tree); you cannot add the same `ComboBoxItem` to more than one `ComboBox`.

Comment: So then how would I accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: Ideally, you should use an object model to represent the items shown in the combo boxes (which are not UI elements and can therefore be shared), and set an `ItemTemplate` to tell each `ComboBox` how to render the backing object (e.g., with a label and an image).  I don't have time to write up a proper answer before I leave the office, but I figured I could at least nudge you in the right direction or give someone else a head start on an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic WPF example. Please have a look at MVVM patter, WPF data binding and data templates.

**View definition**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Window.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Height="44" Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

    <ComboBox x:Name="cbOne" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemTemplate}"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cbTwo" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemTemplate}"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cbThree" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemTemplate}"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cbFour" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemTemplate}"/>

</StackPanel>
```

**CodeBehind**

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<ImageInfo> _images;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _images = new ObservableCollection<ImageInfo>(GetImages());

        cbOne.ItemsSource = _images;
        cbTwo.ItemsSource = _images;
        cbThree.ItemsSource = _images;
        cbFour.ItemsSource = _images;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ImageInfo> GetImages()
    {
        const string path = @"C:\_D\_Log\";

        var items = from x in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.png")
                    select new ImageInfo
                    {
                        ImageUrl = x,
                        Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(x)
                    };
        return items;
    }
}

public class ImageInfo
{
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I've run into one issue however... The images get "locked" and I can't edit them while the program is running. Is there a setting I can do to fix this?